# How to run Neural network developed in CNTK on a Azure Sphere board

Tags: cntk, azure-sphere

I have a neural network developed using CNTK and I am looking for a way to have that neural network deployed on a Azure Sphere device. The network is an ANN and is not that compute intensive. Can anyone please point me to a tool or documentation on how I can run a neural network on Azure Sphere board?

I looked at the documentation for CNTK and it says that it can be used with C++, C# and python. But the Azure sphere documentation says that it only supports C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is to train the model in cntk, save it as an [ONNX](https://onnx.ai/) model. And use [ONNX Runtime](https://github.com/Microsoft/onnxruntime) to execute it in Azure Sphere board. Onnx Runtime has a C API.